# Is there a way to use an enhanced for loop to copy an array?

Tags: java, foreach, copy

I just started using the enhance for-loop. I want to know if I can use this loop to copy an array. I want to iterate through every element of a certain array and copy it to a new one. It  would also be nice to use the enhanced for-loop to instantiate my new array (instead of a typical for-loop). In my current implementation I do know how big I want the array to be, but for future reference I would like to know if I can do this, and if so, how.

My specific plans for what I'm doing might help to answer my question. What I am doing is retrieving a line of text from a text file then calling split( "," ) on that string - this returns an array of Strings. I want to store this array in memory so I can play with it later.

The way I understand the enhanced for-loop to work is that the first value is assigned the current position in the array and the second value is the array that is to be traversed.

I was wondering if there are other formats for for-loops, besides: for ( initialization; termination; iterate ) and for ( Object o : list[] ).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the regular for-loop? For copying an array [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) might be useful.

Comment: "... besides: `for ( initialization; termination; iterate )` and `for ( Object o : list[] )` there is also `for(T o : Iterable<T>)` like Lists for instance http://ideone.com/EsbJop

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep to the enhanced for loop for copying an array, there is one mayor problem: the enhanced for loop doesn't have a counter. Inserting elements into an array however requires a counter. So you could of course do this manually like so:

```
String[] array = {"A", "Bb", "c", "dD"};
String[] newArray = new String[array.length];

int i=0;
for(String stuff : array) {
    newArray[i++] = stuff;
}
```

This is entirely possible but not really the idea behind the enhanced for loop.

More in line with the intention would be something like this:

```
String[] array = {"A", "Bb", "c", "dD"};
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String stuff : array) {
    list.add(stuff);
}

String[] newArray = new String[list.size()];
list.toArray(newArray);
```

That way not only do you follow the idea behind the enhanced for loop, you also allow for the possibility that `array.length() != newArray.length()` (because, say, you filtered the array).

EDIT: as of Java 7, there are indeed only the two for loops you mentioned. This may change in future versions though if it seems sensible; after all, the enhanced for loop was only added in Java 5 (as can be seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html)).

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, there are only standard `for(init; termination; iterataion)` loops and for-each `for(type o : iterable)` loops.

First, knowing the size ahead of time shouldn't be a concern. For instantiating the new array use the original array's .length field: `new String[original.length];` as shown below.

Moving along, for what you are doing, the standard for loop is appropriate for two reasons:

1. You would need to nest two for-each loops in order to iterate both
   loops, making it more hassle than a standard for loop. (or add an externally defined counter, as in blalasaadri's solution)
2. More importantly, in the case of a primitive data type or a String, the variable declared before the `:` in the for-each loop represents the *value* of each successive element, and is *not a reference* to the actual element. As such, any changes to the variable are gone once the loop iterates. I'm not sure if this holds for 'normal' objects (ie: not String), as I've not tried, though I want to find out now.

   To illustrate:

   ```
   String[] sArr = {"foobar"};
   for(String s : sArr){
       s = "openbar";
   }
   ```

   is the equivalent of:

   ```
   String[] sArr = {"foobar"};
   String s = sArr[0];
   s = "openbar";
   ```

   Sadly, for sArr[0], there is no open bar, same old foobar.

As for solutions, if you can `import java.util.Arrays;` then try:

```
String[] copyStrings = Arrays.copyOf(arrStrings, arrStrings.length);
```

Or, if you need to roll your own:

```
public String[] copyArray(String[] original){
    String[] dupe = new String[original.length]; //I assume you want equal length
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
        dupe[i] = original[i]; //single iterator traverses both arrays
    }
    return dupe;
}
```

Comment: When you give the example where you're instantiating the String array sArr with the value "foobar." Should the second parameter in your first example's for-loop be the array you made (sArr)? Also, in the body of that for-loop do you mean to assign 's' the value "openbar"?

Comment: Yeah, your correct.  I fixed it now.  I am prone to that sort of error, rendering me sadly reliant upon the IDE to tell me about it.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps I should mention that the intent of those code blocks is to show that even though the String variable is modified, in both cases the String[0] value in the array remains unchanged.  In short, when using the for-each loop like this, the variable which contains the elements value is a temp variable, not the array element itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
// copy contents of Object[] arr1 into Object[] arr2
arr2 = new int[arr1.length];
int i=0;
for(Object c:arr1){ //store an element of arr1 in c iteratively
    arr2[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```